# create a subtraction and division in c using addition only

Tags: c

I have created division through subtraction but i cannot figure it out through addition

```
int divide, divis, quotient;
printf("Enter Number 1:");
scanf("%d", &divide);

printf("Enter Number 2:");
scanf("%d", &divis);
quotient=0;
while(divide > 0){
divide = divide - divis;
quotient++;
}
printf("%d\n, quotient);
```

Comment: Isn't the addition of a negative number subtraction?

Comment: Just FYI. this won't give you correct quotient try for 5 and 2. Chnage while loop condition to (divide >= divis)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting from `divide` and subtracting until you drop below 0, instead start from 0 and add until you exceed `divide`.

Note that you will need to be careful that you don't overflow your number range.

Comment: so would it be the same condition in the while loop or divide < 0

Comment: @helloman: No, like I said, you're counting upwards, so you want to stop when you exceed `divide` (or perhaps `divide - divis` or something similar; I'm too tired to work out which it is!).

Answer (score 1):

If you already have division, you can just divide the subtrahend by -1 and then add the minuend.

Comment: how would u do that in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
int num1,num2,cnt=0;
printf("Please enter num 1: \n");
scanf("%d",&num1);
printf("Please enter num 2: \n");
scanf("%d",&num2);
while(num1>=num2){
num1-=num2;
cnt++;
}
printf("%d",cnt);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a little bit ?